# Are emigration for expats off topic in here?

Tags: discussion

Emigration questions such as 'What is the process to emigrate to UAE for expats" off topic here?

Can questions about emigration allow in here?

Are there exceptions or kinds of questions related to emigration not allow in here?

Are there any stack-exchange site(s) to post questions about emigration If they are not allow in here?

Answer (score 2):

generally on our site everything is on topic if it relates to any complications because of you living, or planning to live in a different country than you were born in and are a citizen.

More specifically based on our [what's on topic](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> Questions about work, residence, student, investor and similar mid and long term visas aimed for staying in the country for more time than a tourist or short term business visa would allow

I think this point covers your question.